# thinkpad middle click in a VMWare doesn't work (guest: Ubuntu and host: windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, thinkpad, vmware-workstation

**problem**:

when i try to paste with middle click, the middle mouse button is ignored. in other cases middle click is also ignored.

**my set up**:

VMWare workstation  7.1.3

*Host*: windows 7 64-bit

*Guest*: existing partition of Ubuntu 10.10.    I have a dual boot (ubuntu,win7) from win7 i log into the ubuntu's partition.

*Hardware*: ThinkPad x201 Tablet

side question: does virtualbox has the same problem?

Comment: I should have asked if you can use the middle mouse click when you dual boot into Ubuntu directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by disabling TrackPoint scrolling in the Windows control panels.

I had the same problem in a VMware Ubuntu guest on a ThinkPad X220 running Windows 7. With the default mouse/trackpoint settings, the middle button wouldn't register at all when running xev in Ubuntu. Presumably some low-level Windows/Lenovo software layer was capturing middle-button events and interpreting them as scroll commands.

You can resolve this by turning off scrolling altogether. In the mouse control panel, you can set TrackPoint scrolling to either "Scrolling," "Magnifying Glass," or "Neither." I was able to paste in Ubuntu using the middle button right after setting the control to "Neither."

Comment: On Windows 10 on a new X1 Carbon, I found this setting under Mouse Settings -> TrackPoint settings -> Middle Button Action -> change from Scrolling to Middle Click. This allowed middle click to open links in new browser tabs in both my VirtualBox Ubuntu guest and my browsers in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

After many painfull months without linux middle button action I decided to insist on finding a solution for my lenovo T510, Win7 host, debian guest.

After hours of trying and search, I finally found it: The "Neither" setting as described by Alan alone is not enough for my model (and I assume for other's too). You also have to set the "scrolling type" (for me, in the "settings" next to the "Neither" setting) to "smooth" !

Thanks UltraNav/Lenovo for offering all kinds of patented obscure scrolling with you eye-lashes-options and thereby rendering the settings rediculously complex.

Answer (score 1):

While Alan and docno jointly have written a complete answer satisfying the question. **It does not fix "Control Scrolling"** which is scrolling you do when holding the middle button and moving the trackpoint to scroll a page.

After a few hours of research I found that you can fix this by letting virtualbox completely propagate the USB device (your keyboard) to the guest. This solution has one advantage:

- The keyboard will be seen directly by the guest and at least on Ubuntu the USB keyboard works right away out of the box. This is not the case for Windows nor OS X according to my own experience.

There is some very serious drawbacks:

- Keyboard becomes totally dead to the host! You can't even use the *Host Key* in virtualbox anymore! However, you can if you have a separate physical keyboard nearby (like the one integrated in your laptop or any other USB keyboard).
- Mouse integration will stop working! altogether. You can however just disable it in VirtualBox with `Ctrl+I`
- Your host will think you're completely idle when using the ThinkPad USB keyboard and the Host's srceensaver will go in on you. It scared the hell out of me when the screen just went dark! Naturally this is just resolved by lengthening the the time limit.

I wish I had seen this earlier as I wouldn't had to download any Windows drivers for my USB keyboard in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu/Gnome doesn't natively treat the middle mouse button as a scrolling wheel. I think it does something odd like paste from clipboard.

You'll need to configure it manually.

For a graphically utility, you can install GPointing Device Settings by running

```
sudo aptitude install sysfsutils
```

See: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint